# jquery $.fn access object from html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, javascript-objects

I'm trying to get object options and functions from an html element.
I have

```
$.fn.test = function(options){ 

  var me = this;

  this.create = function(){

    me.settings = $.extend({
      foo: 'foo'
    }, options);

    console.log('foo');
  }

  this.hello = function(){
    console.log('hello');
  }

  return this;

}
```

On document ready I create my object

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var obj = $('#mydiv').test({
    foo: 'bar';
  });
  obj.create();
});
```

In another document I'm tryng to get settings from #mydiv like:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
  var x = $('#mydiv').test();
  //x.create();
  console.log(x.settings.foo);
});
```

If in the last section I call create function it shows me 'foo', not 'bar'. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(options) me.settings = $.extend({
  foo: 'foo'
}, options);
```

just override .settings if theres actually an options object..

And im not shure if jquery embeds function chaining so you may do:

```
this.hello = function(){
 console.log('hello');
 return this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I must get function in an other js document. It return me the initial value